# Css flex box does not align labels, and text inputs properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that the labels and text inputs in my html code, when below a certain screen width, will line up in a straight line, with 1 label and 1 text input per row. When it is above the max screen width, I want it to line up in rows of 3.
Currently, it lines up in rows of 3, but when it reaches the max screen width, it doesn't line up in a line, with 1 label and text input per row, the label, and the input, shows different rows, and are completely misaligned.  The effect is similar as if I did display: block for the labels.
Here is my HTML code, that I am trying to use flexbox on.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 696px) {
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
   <h3 id="question"></h3>
   <label id="S" for = "Sn"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "Sn" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <label id="at" for = "atomic"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "atomic" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <label id="elec" for = "electrons"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "electrons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <h3 id="question2"></h3>
   <label id="pro" for = "protons"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "protons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <label id="ma" for = "mass"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "mass" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <label id="ele" for = "element"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "element" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <h3 id="question3"></h3>
   <label id="pro2" for = "protons2"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "protons2" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <label id="at2" for = "atomic2"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "atomic2" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   <label id="new" for = "neutrons"></label>
   <input type = "text" id = "neutrons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
</div>
```

here is what it looks like now, All the labels are above the text inputs-[image]
I want the labels to be aligned with the text inputs.

Comment: you forgot to add a closing ```}``` with your CSS code

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-direction: column;` instead of row on your media query.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 696px) {
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
 }
 #boxes > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 1rem;
 }
}

label {
  text-align: left;
}

label#S {
  margin-right: .65rem;
}

label#elec {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
   <h3 id="question"></h3>
   <div>
     <label id="S" for = "Sn">Proton</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "Sn" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label id="at" for = "atomic">Neutron</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "atomic" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label id="elec" for = "electrons">Electron</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "electrons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   
   <h3 id="question2"></h3>
   <div>
     <label id="S" for = "Sn">Proton</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "Sn" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label id="at" for = "atomic">Neutron</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "atomic" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label id="elec" for = "electrons">Electron</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "electrons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <h3 id="question3"></h3>
   <div>
     <label id="S" for = "Sn">Proton</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "Sn" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label id="at" for = "atomic">Neutron</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "atomic" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label id="elec" for = "electrons">Electron</label>
     <input type = "text" id = "electrons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that still doesn't work

Comment: @Joshua I'm confused about what you want then. Please provide a markup image of your desired result.

Comment: Okay, I put it in my question, what it looks like now. I want the labels and the text inputs to be aligned.

Comment: @Joshua see the adjusted answer... This is based on your screenshot and includes nesting divs for each input and label, I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks that really helped!